# Why is the template parameter losing constness?

Tags: c++, templates, interface

I thought this is a very basic question but I could not find something similar.

The following code does not compile (C3668)

```
struct Param
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    virtual void doStuff (const T) const = 0;
};

struct Bar : public Foo<Param&>
{
    void doStuff (const Param &) const override
    {
        /*...*/
    }
};
```

It will compile after removing the const from

```
void doStuff (const Param &)
```

What am I missing here? I would expect to enforce to the `const Param& in Foo::doStuff` with my interface declaration. Instead it seems to be removed.

Comment: Top-level const is ignored in function declarations.  Also, `const T` would mean `Param& const` , not `const Param&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const` isn't just a text substitution, it applies to the entire type `T`.

If `T` is `Param&`, `const T` and `const Param&` are not equivalent; the former is the same as `Param& const`, which is equivalent to `Param&`.
It becomes more obvious if you write the less common "postfix-const" form: `T const` and `Param const &` can't be equivalent regardless of what `T` is.

Thus, your "override" doesn't override anything and you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
doStuff (const T)
```

it is not the same type as

```
doStuff (const Param &)
```

The first one is a constant whatever T is so in this case you have a constant reference to a T which really doesn't make sense since references cannot be rebound. In the later it is a reference to a `const Param`.

What you could do is change

```
struct Bar : public Foo<Param&>
```

to

```
struct Bar : public Foo<Param>
```

and then

```
virtual void doStuff (const T) const = 0;
```

to

```
virtual void doStuff (const T&) const = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not with const .Problem is with the override.
Member function declared with override doesn't override a base class member